# I can't get access to protected url after auth

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I have

```
    USERNAME = USERNAME  # put correct usename here
    PASSWORD = PASSWORD  # put correct password here

    LOGINURL = 'http://secure.mozy.com/login/'
    DATAURL = 'http://secure.mozy.com/account/download'
    proxyDict = {
        'http': 'http://...',
        'https': 'https://...'
    }

session = requests.Session()
    session.proxies.update(proxyDict)
    session.headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36'}
    result = session.get(LOGINURL)
    tree = html.fromstring(result.text)
    token = tree.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/input/@value')
    print token
    payload = {
        'authenticity_token': token[0],
        'username': USERNAME,
        'password': PASSWORD
    }
    print payload
    result = session.post(LOGINURL,data= payload, headers= dict(referer = LOGINURL))
    result2 = session.get(DATAURL,headers = dict(referer=DATAURL))
    print result2.text
    buff = html.fromstring(result2.text)
    ver = buff.xpath('//*[@id="maincontent"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]')
    print ver
```

I need pass auth in http://secure.mozy.com/login/ 
And get content from http://secure.mozy.com/account/download  after auth

But after `result = session.post(LOGINURL,data= payload, headers= dict(referer = LOGINURL))` I don't have access to DATAURL... Please help me!)

Comment: Have you tried debugging and checking the value of `result` (the response) and seeing if you are indeed authenticated?

Comment: Yes , of course, my code doesn't pass authentication. 'result' return page code of 'LOGINURL'